# Find the probability of $P(B|-A)$ given $P(B)$, $P(A|B)$, $P(A|-B)$?

Tags: probability

$A,B,C$ not independent

I've found $P(-A)$, $P(-B \cap A)$, $P(A \cap B)$

$P(A)$ = $P(-B \cap A)$ + $P(A \cap B)$

Bayes Rule isn't helping me find $P(-A \cap B)$ or $P(B|-A)$  as far as I can see.

Edit: Added $P(A)$

Comment: What is $-A$? ${}{}{}$

Comment: It is $\Omega - A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $-A$ denotes the complement of $A$ we have by Bayes rule that $$P(B|A^c)=\frac{P(A^c|B)P(B)}{P(A^c)}=\frac{\left(1-P(A|B)\right)P(B)}{1-P(A)}$$ which should be given according to the exercise (except for $P(A)$ which you have found as you say).